# NameError when printing numpy object on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013

I am typing this in immediate window of Visual Studio 2013 and getting NameError.

```
arr=np.array([1,2,3])
print(arr)
NameError
```

I would like to print the content of numpy array but I can't see no matter what I do. What am I doing wrong?
I have Python35-32.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you have properly imported `numpy` before trying these commands.

Try:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,2,3])
print(arr)
```

Comment: Ok now, it prints "None" but at least it prints the values on that black command prompt rather than in VS. I wasn't expecting this.